# Prevent the user from scrolling when using overflow: auto in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

So I have this `<div />` with `overflow: auto`. Inside of it are some `<input type="text" />` elements. Half of the div is hidden; the user is supposed to click some navigation links to hide the first half and show the second half.

It turns out that, in Chrome (not in Firefox or IE), if the user puts his cursor inside the `<input type="text" />`, then drags it to the right, he can make the `<div />` "scroll" to the right and show the second half of its content!!

The best I can come up with to prevent this is some kind of stupid `setInterval` check that will reposition the div if necessary. Is there anything cleaner?

Comment: Do you have have to do it like this ? Seems you could use two divs and use the CSS display property to show/hide the correct div.

Comment: Well actually I want to use jQuery animations to show the "movement" from the first half to the second half, which seems to require a structure like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  width:400px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.container .content {
  width:800px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

The contents are twice as wide as the container, but the second half is hidden. To display the second half, simply set `right:0;` (or `left:-400px;`) on the `.content` div.

#### update

Set the width of the content to the width of the container (400px in this example) until you're ready to show the second part, then resize the content to 800px and move it to display the new content.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing. The problem is that if you put an `<input type="text" />` inside `<div class="content" />`, the user can "grab" that `input` and use it to "scroll" to the second half.